# Can I comment directly on attachments in Trello?

Tags: trello, comments

My UX team at work has been using Trello during our sprints, and while we love so much of the functionality, its commenting/activity system makes it difficult to give feedback on particular attachments. This can be a bear especially with iterative design. Is it possible to comment directly on an attachment or is there an extension available to solve this?